# php session echo intval with decimals

Tags: php, session, echo

Hello now my code looks like:

```
echo number_format($_SESSION['price_summ']."<br>");
```

But I need to have numbers with decimals... I know it should look something like this:

```
$row['price'] = intval(($row['price']*100))/100;
```

But it Does not work.

Comment: Ummmm integers don't have decimals.  Please explain.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide some test input and output showing in what way it is failing to work?

Comment: use floatval() to get decimal point of an integer

Comment: @NishanthMatha - "use floatval() to get a float instead of an integer"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to store your data in database with type of DECIMAL or FLOAT or DOUBLE. And when you will output data from database it will already be in decimal format. Which type to use is relative. Look threw the web to find optimal solution for your situation.

If you want to use PHP use [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)

`$num = "18";
echo number_format((float)$num, 2, '.', '');  //echo will output 105.00`

Answer (score 0):

Its really a lot confusing line

```
echo number_format($_SESSION['price_summ']."<br>");
```

I guess you want to convert `$_SESSION['price_summ']` to float .
Use `floatval()` for it.

```
echo number_format(floatval($_SESSION['price_summ']))."<br>";
```

Alsi you put the bracket after `"<br>"` which is wrong. In your second code segment you ate simply doing nothing if you `$row['price']` is an integer. If it is an integer, go for this

```
$row['price'] = intval(($row['price']*100.0))/100;
```